# Weird behavior with promises

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I'm doing some tests with promises and I wrote a code that is not behaving quite the way I was expecting:

```
function function1() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let i = 5000000000;
    while (i > 0) {
      i--;
    }
    resolve("print function1!!!");
  });
}

function function2() {
  console.log("print function2!!!");
}

function function3() {
  function1().then(data => console.log(data));
  function2();
}

function3();
```

the execution of this code waits for the completion of the loop in function1 and then print:

> print function2!!!
>
> print function1!!!

I was expecting that the code would print "print function2!!!" then wait for the completion of the loop and then print "print function1!!!".

Why the loop inside the promise is blocking the execution of the code?

Comment: For the behavior you want you'd need to use something like `setTimeout` so other code has a chance to run.

Comment: if I wrap the loop in the setTimeout it works, I was expecting the promises to run asynchronously.

Comment: The loop is irrelevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why the loop inside the promise is blocking the execution of the code?

That's the JavaScript execution model (in Browsers and Node). Your code never gets pre-empted, code always runs from start to finish and can only "register" code for the platform to run at a later time.

The promise constructor runs synchronously. Promises don't introduce threading into your code and they only defer running code in `then` callbacks to "after all synchronous code" but before all platform code.

Promises are just a handle for a future value - they don't make your code execute on another thread. If you need to run code on another thread you need to either use `worker_threads` (in Node.js) or web workers in browsers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your promise does not contain any asynchronous code.
If you do not want to wait for the code inside the promise of function1 to be executed you need to write it e.g. in a setTimeout.

```
function function1() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      let i = 5000000000;
      while (i > 0) {
        i--;
      }
      resolve("print function1!!!");
    }, 0);
  });
}

function function2() {
  console.log("print function2!!!");
}

function function3() {
  function1().then(data => console.log(data));
  function2();
}

function3();
```